# C# Regex to get ID value from HTML

Tags: c#, regex

I want to use a regex expression to extract an ID value from a web-response which I get from a website.

This is the line which has the id value required:

```
SONET.globalSettings = $.extend(SONET.globalSettings, {"esc_my_persona":"1234566","esc_my_player":"1234567","esc_my_nucleus":"123456677","esc_my_platform":"cem_ea_id"}
```

I need to get the value of esc_my_nuclues...that is: 123456677.

Help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
string regex=@"esc_my_nucleus"":""(\d+)";
string val=Regex.Match(input,regex,RegexOptions.Ignorecase).Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using ASP.NET and the JavaScript library is making an HTTP GET, then the name-value pairs should be in the query part of the URL. Hence:

```
var val = HttpContext.Request.QueryString["esc_my_nucleus"];
```

If the JavaScript is performing an HTTP POST then you need to extract from the request body

```
var val = HttpContext.Request.Form["esc_my_nucleus"];
```

Or use `HttpContext.Request.Params` which combines both the above.

However knowing the server side framework (WebForms, MVC or something else?) and how that JavaScript is expressed as an HTTP request would allow a better answer.

**NB**. none of these needs a regex: even if you are parsing the URL yourself regular expressions are unlikely to be the right answer (too much flexibility in what a URL can contain, too easy to open security vulnerabilities).